# Change Button custom shape states color programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, button, colors

There are a lot of answers on this site regarding changing button colors, but none that I  have managed to use in my case.

I want to be able to dynamically change a button's color, that button still needs to have a visual feedback on press, and it needs rounded corners.

The rounded corners part was decided upon recently, so previously I used something like this:

```
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
         new ColorDrawable(hsvDarkenColor(theme.get_buttonsBgColor())));
         states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
        new ColorDrawable(hsvDarkenColor(theme.get_buttonsBgColor())));
         states.addState(new int[]{},
       new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(theme.get_buttonsBgColor())));
     ((Button) button).setBackgroundDrawable(states);

//this is for the focused/pressed state of the button
   private static int hsvDarkenColor(String originalColor)
        {
            float[] hsv = new float[3];
            int color = Color.parseColor(originalColor);
            Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
            hsv[2] *= 0.8f; // value component
            return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        }
```

However this doesn't preserve the rounded corners shape of the buttons, it makes them into squares.

My default buttons' backgrounds are a list of states each with it's own drawable, for pressed and unpressed, etc.

In styles.xml:

```
    <style name="xx.Light.ScanButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/xx_scan_button</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_light</item>
    </style>
```

In drawable/xx_scan_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_normal"
    />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_pressed"
    />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_pressed"
    />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_pressed"
    />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_pressed"
    />

<!-- Disabled -->
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/xx_scan_button_normal"
    />
</selector>
```

And in drawable/xx_scan_button_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"             android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
         android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
<solid
    android:color="#C74700"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
</shape>
```

**TL;DR:** I need some way to extract the shape drawable from a drawable state list from a button in order to change it's color.
 Or if you guys have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make separate drawables for individual color and change drawable programmatically not color. Changing color from program overrides the drawble.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I need to let the user select his own color from a very wide array of colors. I wouldn't be able to create drawables for all of them. (Wasn't my decision :) )